# How to get the current latitude and longitude as double in android?

Tags: android, gps, google-latitude

According to this demo: [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800886/how-to-refresh-the-marker-on-the-map)

I want to get my current latitude as double or as String. via Internet or gps

But I thing via Internet better, at the time i use gps like that :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyLocation(); }

public void MyLocation() { 
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 1, this);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    a_lat =String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    a_lon =String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

To request, you must use Location Manager and call location listener. In the method onLocationChanged(), you can access lattitude and longitude by : 
loc.getlatitude() and loc.getlongitude().

You should also add permission checks as location comes under **dangerous permission group** according to android deveopers https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Further, this github repo worked fine for me:

https://github.com/Shobhit95Sharma/Gps_location/blob/master/app/src/main/java/testing/gps_location/MainActivity.java

Comment: (according to github code ) : this is the code what I use at the moment. but the problem, you do not get the current position if you do not move. we get the lat/lon after **OnChanged**  if i go outside an go wallking for a few minutes and try again, then it works

Comment: there is other methode, it gets the current location using the both sources **(Internet and gps)**  like here below but i could not implement the Idea **:( :**   show here :  [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)